# How to validate one big form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I will try to explain my problem:
I have one form (I can make second, but i want to have one). And I want to validate the form Using **HTML5** or by **Jquery plugin for validation** and the problem is:

One of the form-fields are for registred users and another one is for new users. So I need to detect valid form or focused? Because HTML5 wan to validate full form.  How you are solving this problem? BTW: I'm using Bootstrap 3.

For Exp:

```
<div class="col-md-12 well">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                 <form id="checkout-login" action="" method="post">  
            <h3>Existing User</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-fancy" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" required="required" autocomplete="on">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Heslo</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-fancy" id="password" placeholder="********" name="password" required="required" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
             </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
             <h3>New user</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-fancy" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" required="required" autocomplete="on">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-fancy" id="surname" placeholder="Priezvisko" name="surname" required="required" autocomplete="on">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-fancy" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" required="required" autocomplete="on">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Heslo</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-fancy" id="password" placeholder="********" name="password" required="required" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                 </div>
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-green btn-lg" value="Pokračovať"></input>
            </form>

         </div>
```

JQuery, please help me with ** and you can ignore //

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $("form").submit(function (e) { e.preventDefault() });
    if(**find valid form){
    $("**then $(this) is valid --> send").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '',
            data: //my custom,
            success: function (data) {
                //Show Thank you
            },
            cache: false
        });
    });
   }else{
     //Show alert please register or login
   }
});
```

Thank you for any answer, advice or comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the validation plugin  [jquery validate demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/), i used it with bootstrap. It has lots of option for customization. That makes a good choice if you’re building something new from scratch, but also when you’re trying to integrate it into an existing application with lots of existing markup. The plugin comes bundled with a useful set of validation methods, including URL and email validation, while providing an API to write your own methods. All bundled methods come with default error messages in english and translations into 37 locales.

Code is available on https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation